# Is there any way in Java to delete an element from the memory?

Tags: java

Say that I want to create a class object with a *JOptionPane* dialog. In the constructor I assign the variables and other stuff, and the user presses cancel. Of course I want to delete that thing, because it is half made and could be buggy. Is there **any way** to do this in **java**?

Comment: You just have to remove all references to the object in the stack and the heap and the object will be unreachable and eligible for collection. The other way you can do this is use native resources / JNI (See Java.awt.Window.dispose for an example)

Answer (score 8):

> and the user presses cancel

That shouldn't be happening in an object's constructor anyway. A constructor is for constructing an object **only**.

Get the input from the user first, and only invoke the constructor if they choose to proceed. If they press cancel, don't invoke the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The JVM automatically frees memory. Read about [Java's garbage collector](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html).